# convert formatted mac address to an hex value

Tags: powershell, mac-address

I have a mac address as a string in the following format: `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` (six groups of two hexadecimal digits, separated by colons).

I want to convert the string into it's respective hex value (as a `System.Byte` type).

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this?

```
 "00:0a:fe:25:af:db" -split ':' | % { [byte]"0x$_" }
```

Edit after comment:

this?

```
  [UInt64] "0x$("00:0a:fe:25:af:db" -replace ':')"
```

Comment: I actually reached that far, but I don't know how to turn this list into a joint hex value now.

Comment: what is a "joint hex value" ??

Comment: @iTayb but this is the original mac without `:`... you want this?

Comment: Yes, that's what i needed, just converted it to [UInt64] type. Thanks